# Handling strings coherently with pandas, numpy and basic- Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

I really think that the pandas/numpy basic Python interplay with string type needs some fixes. At least it isn't intuitive or user-friendly at all: Look at the code below (I know some things are wrong - but imagine it from a new user perspective.):

```
# Create a df with a string column
# The column should obviously be treated as a string - but it will be object
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a","b", "c"]})

# The values attribute gives a numpy array of dtype object: -> cast it via np.str_ 
# then we have a numpy string array
df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_)

# Feed it back into a Series -> won't retain the string attribute - still object
pd.Series(df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_))
# Obvioulsy the dtype argument here doesn't work - why does it not result in an error #message if it is a useless/nonsensical specification for a dtype argument?
pd.Series(df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_), dtype=np.str_)
# Same as above: Useless dtype argument. Still no warning message - a user might no think that everything is treated as a string
pd.Series(df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_), dtype=str)
# Ok this works
pd.Series(df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_), dtype='string')
#But feeding it back to numpy does not give a proper numpy array.
pd.Series(df.iloc[:,0].values.astype(np.str_), dtype='string').values
```

In addition, I didn't touch upon the issue of handling missing values. As I think, np.nan is the only missing value numpy provides - but it is of type float.

So my question: What is the safest way to handle strings - if the code requires switching/interplay between pandas/numpy and basic python? Any advices would be great!

Comment: Python strings can vary in length.  `numpy` arrays have to contain elements with a consistent length (`.itemsize`).  Thus strings are stored with a `Un` dtype (or `Sn` for bytestrings).  `pandas` uses `object` dtype to store 'raw' python strings (actually it's references to strings elsewhere in memory).  Hence all the conversion stuff that's confusing. `df.to_numpy(dtype=object)` makes a matching array.  `pandas` is adding an experimental `StringDtype`.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html